# How to redirect one selected item on data gridview to another data gridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datagridview

I'm using vb.net. I have successfully query out this in data gridview by using sql 
[image]

After I click the "Performance", I want to query out the details of "LM3409QHVMYUY8" and the details is inside the oracle and display into another data grid view
How I'm going to that ?
Thanks

I'm used this code to get the above datagridview:

```
    Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connCommon")
    Dim sqlConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT * FROM ODS_Nspn_Pkg_Group_v WHERE ([SAG-Grp] = '" & ddlPackage & "')"

    Dim sqlCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0

    Dim dataAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

    Return dataSet
```

Comment: What code are you using to produce the above?

Comment: What Chris said, and also what have you tried? I would also like to know if this is for web or desktop.

Comment: datagridview is obviously `Winforms`. Check this: [DataGridVIew.CellClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx) and after that show us what did you try...

Comment: @Chris I had include the code above

Comment: @WozzeC this is for web